# If (multiple condition) ... else

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a if else statement with two conditions has to meet by the first "IF". But I couldn't make it work and with not one but few syntax errors. Appreciated if any of you could help.

Here is how I wrote the code:

```
Declare 
    is_null Integer := 10;
    Wrong_record :=2;

If (is_null > 0 or wrong_record > 0 )
Begin

Insert INTO table name (column1, column2, .......)
Values
    ( value1, value2,........);

ElSE

    Insert INTO table name (column1, column2, .......)
   Values
    ( value1, value2,........);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: you swithced the BEGIN and the IF , and need to add a THEN after the conditions

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare 
    is_null      pls_integer := 10;
    Wrong_record pls_integer :=  2;
Begin
 If ( is_null > 0 or wrong_record > 0 ) Then
  Begin -- this "begin .. end " statement is not required but stands for readability
   Insert Into table_name (column1, column2, .......)
   Values( value1, value2,........);
  End; 
 Else
   Begin -- this "begin .. end " statement is not required but stands for readability
    Insert Into table_name (column1, column2, .......)
    Values( value1, value2,........);
   End;
 End if;
End;
```

Comment: @StevenHuang excuse me, i've realised that i left as `table name`, instead of `table_name`. Now, i corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sure it would work, but when I tried it gives me "invalid number" on "If ( is_null > 0 or wrong_record > 0 ) ". Also when run the code I keep getting "anonymous block completed" message. Do you know why?

Comment: @StevenHuang  
"anonymous block completed" means your PL/SQL code was successfully executed. I think you issued "set serveroutput on" formerly, and you get this message. Not problem.

Comment: I have write SQL like this: 
    Declare 
        is_null Number := 10; 
       Wrong_record Number := 2;
    Begin 
    If ( is_null > 0 or wrong_record > 0 ) Then 
    Begin 
      Insert Into table_name (column1, column2, .......) 
    Values( value1, value2,is_null, wrong_record,........); 
    End; 
    Else 
    Begin
    Insert Into table_name (column1, column2, .......) 
    Values( value1, value2,is_null, wrong_record, ........);
    End;  
    End if; 
    End;

Comment: @StevenHuang ok, did you get the values inserted into your table?

Comment: No not insert successfully. It saying Invalid number message... I don't get it. I have put these two variable I declare within the Values (is_null, wrong_records, ......) don't know why it doesn't take it

Comment: @StevenHuang you can not use double equal sign(==), but single sign could be used in pl/sql. For comparison, Use `is_null = 0`, instead of `is_null == 0`.